# PW characters type and length integration fails

Tags: php

I use the following script-part to modify my pw:

```
if ( !empty($_POST['pass1'] ) && !empty( $_POST['pass2'] ) ) {
    if ( $_POST['pass1'] == $_POST['pass2'] )
        wp_update_user( array( 'ID' => $current_user->ID, 'user_pass' => esc_attr( $_POST['pass1'] ) ) );
    else
        $error[] = __('Password doesn't match.', 'profile');
}
```

... and I try to add **characters type and pw length**:

```
if ( !empty($_POST['pass1'] ) && !empty( $_POST['pass2'] ) ) {
    if ( $_POST['pass1'] == $_POST['pass2']  && !preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/', $_POST['pass1'], $_POST['pass2']) || strlen($_POST['pass1'], $_POST['pass2']) < 8)
        wp_update_user( array( 'ID' => $current_user->ID, 'user_pass' => esc_attr( $_POST['pass1'] ) ) );
    else
        $error[] = __('Password doesn't match.', 'profile');
}
```

... but it fails. Whats wrong (Sorry, I am not a php pro)?

Comment: `|| strlen($_POST['pass1'], $_POST['pass2']) < 8` change it to `|| (strlen($_POST['pass1']) < 8 && strlen($_POST['pass2']) < 8))`

Comment: same for `preg_match` also

Comment: Your `||` condition is going to bite you, if the first part results in `false` but the password length is larger than 8 it will update. If you are not that familiar with PHP I would go for nested `if` statement. Once inside the `if ( $_POST['pass1'] == $_POST['pass2'] )` you only have to check one of the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `preg_match` and `strlen` functions do their work on one operand at a time. That's why `strlen($_POST['pass1'], $_POST['pass2'])` is a **wrong** function call. Proper call is:

```
strlen($_POST['pass1']) < 8 || strlen($_POST['pass2']) < 8
```

Same stuff for `pregmatch`:

```
!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/', $_POST['pass1']) || !preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/', $_POST['pass2'])
```

And in the end your full `if` is not clear. It you want to check for symbols and for password length do this:

```
if ( $_POST['pass1'] == $_POST['pass2']  
    && preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/', $_POST['pass1']) 
    && strlen($_POST['pass1']) >= 8)
```

Here we check if passwords match, and `pass1` matches regexp and `pass1` has allowed length.

Note, that I **removed checks** for `pass2` because if passwords match - there's no need to check `pass2`, as it's the same as `pass1`. Also if passwords differ - other checks will not be executed as `$_POST['pass1'] == $_POST['pass2']`  is already `false`.

Comment: Thx for support! Ah, ok, ... I will try it!

Comment: Nice way to check, really interesting! Big thx, it works perfect!